# Flipping a card, CSS animation for web app

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, flip, card

I've managed to build a card in React with a front and backside and have it flip successfully on hover with CSS. However, I want to flip it on click/touch.

I tried setting the transform property to a class and toggling that class on click but no luck.

How would you accomplish this?

This is how I am currently flipping it via hover:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  perspective: 1000px;
} 
 
.card > * {
  width: 10rem;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover > .card__front {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover > .card__back {
transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

and my JSX

```
        <div className={styles.card} >
          {/* FRONTSIDE */}
            <div className={styles.card__front}>
              //FRONTSIDE CONTENT
            </div>

            {/* BACKSIDE */}
            <div className={styles.card__back}>
               //BACKSIDE CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
```

### UPDATE

This function works, it toggles the flip class on and off on my desired element. However, no animation happens once the class is added. The .flip class does the exact same thing as the :hover did though..

```
 //function to toggle class
 const flip = (element) => {
    console.log(element);
    element.classList.toggle("flip");
  };

//the css class
.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that React won't rerender the DOM when a class is added with the .toggle method.

The solution was to create a state out of the classlist and add the class from the classlist by using the setState method. This triggers a rerender

```
//JS
const [classlist, setClasslist] = useState(styles.card)

const flip = () => {
setClasslist(classlist + styles.flip)
}

//HTML
<div className={classlist} onClick={() => flip()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use js to add a style to the element.

What you forgot to add is pretty simple, you forgot transition: transform 1s on the class and perspective: 1000px. The more less the more intense the effect is.

HTML:-

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="card-warpper">
  <span onclick="flipCard()" class="card">
    <div class="front">
      Aye
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Bye
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:- (You will edit it based on your needs)

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card-warpper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card-clicked {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: antiquewhite;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Finally, JS:-

```js
function flipCard() {
  let card = document.getElementsByClassName("card")[0];
  card.classList.toggle("card-clicked");
}
```

Comment: Hey Aly. I actually do have those CSS properties on my card__front and card__back classes. Like I said, this works perfectly on :hover but not by adding a class.

Comment: These properties shall go on the card it self ;-; Just check my code, it works perfect.

Comment: Turns out React won't rerender the dom when a class is added with the .toggle method.

Comment: Oh, I didnt notice that, gonna work on it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still learning javascript but this is what i came up with...

I made a snippet using javascript, you can click the "card" and it goes to the back and when you "mouse out" it rotates back to front or if you comment out the second cards.forEach and you can click another card and it rotates back to front and the card you clicked rotates to the back.

I made a class called ".card__inner.is-flipped". With the "cards" variable declared in the javascript that targets all of the ".card__inner"'s i added and removed the ".is-flipped" class on "click" and "mouseleave" to each card.

```js
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card__inner');

cards.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        cards.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-flipped'));
        el.classList.add('is-flipped');
    });
});

cards.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        cards.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-flipped'));
    });
});
```

```css
.cardRowWrapper { //RowWrapper  CARD
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 45rem;
    height: 35rem;
    perspective: 800px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.card__inner { //Skills circle
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 12rem;
    width: 12rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.card__inner.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: yellow;
}

.card__face {
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
    display: flex;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card__face--back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
            <div class="cardRowWrapper">
                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card__inner">
                        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
                          <p>This is the front</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
                            <span class="skillsSubHeading">This is the back</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Okay so that's basically what I tried.

I have a function that adds (I also tried toggle) 'flip' class to the frontside, but it doesn't get added. I have made sure that I am targeting the correct div.

 const flipCard = () => {
    document.querySelector(`.${styles.card__front}`).classList.add(".flip");
  };

Maybe the fact that I am using react changes anything?

Comment: and the console is not returning any syntax errors? you must not be targeting the class right if it isnt being added, all the spelling is the same? i'm not sure what you're doing with .card__back:active and .card__front:active if you're enabling the class with ".flip" shouldnt you do card__back.flip card__front.flip?

Comment: No syntax errors.

If I set my targeted dom element as a variable and console.log that variable, I get it logged in my console.

The :active class is a different method I was trying, unrelated to the javascript method.

Comment: There was an element in my way. The class now toggles on and off on the correct element but no animation happens.